# Android httpGET JSON array

Tags: java, php, android, https

GOAL: Call this function and look into an array of JSON returned from php and see if element[0] or [1] == 1. PHP queries a table of booleans and I want to know which are 1 and 0 in order to continue functionality.

I have this function to perform a httpGET and return a JSON object

```
  class CheckVotingStatus extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    boolean failure = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Vote.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Checking vote Status...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Check for success tag
        int success;

        try {
            // Building Parameters


            Log.d("request!", "starting");
            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(LOGIN_URL);

            // check your log for json response
           // Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
               // Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());

                JSONArray answerObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ANSWER);

                // get first product object from JSON Array
               JSONObject answer = answerObj.getJSONObject(0);
                String bool1s = answer.getString(TAG_BOOL1);
                JSONObject answer2 = answerObj.getJSONObject(1);
                String bool2s = answer2.getString(TAG_BOOL2);

                /******************************************/
                if (bool1s.equals("1")&& bool2s.equals("0"))
                {
                   startVoting = true;
                }
                else if (bool1s.equals("0")&& bool2s.equals("1"))
                {
                    endVoting = true;
                    voted = false;

                }
                /*******************************************/
                //return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }
            else
            {
                //Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                //return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url != null){
            Toast.makeText(Vote.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

My PHP page queries to return two bools from a database

```
$response = array();
$resttt = "SELECT startingBool, endingBool FROM vote_count";
$result = mysql_query("$resttt");
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $answer = array();
    $answer["startingBool"] = $result["startingBool"];            
    $answer["endingBool"] = $result["endingBool"];
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;

    $response["answer"] = array();

    array_push($response["answer"], $answer);

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);

}
```

I'm getting an end of input exception and an err for no value for answer

JSON PARSER

```
 public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(final String url) {


    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // Construct the client and the HTTP request.
        //DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpClient httpClient = createHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        // Execute the POST request and store the response locally.
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        // Extract data from the response.
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        // Open an inputStream with the data content.
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        // Create a BufferedReader to parse through the inputStream.
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        // Declare a string builder to help with the parsing.
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // Declare a string to store the JSON object data in string form.
        String line = null;

        // Build the string until null.
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        // Close the input stream.
        is.close();
        // Convert the string builder data to an actual string.
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // Try to parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        Log.v("JSON", json);
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // Return the JSON Object.
    return jObj;

}
```

Comment: did you have a look at GSON ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your echo from php must be like this

{"success":1,"answer":[{"bool1":"0","bool2":"1"}]}

and your php skript

```
//conect to database, create table bool_table, insert data to bool_table.......


$response = array();
$resttt = "SELECT bool1, bool2 FROM bool_table";
$result = mysql_query("$resttt");
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        $answer = array();
        $answer["bool1"] = $result["bool1"];            
        $answer["bool2"] = $result["bool2"];
        // success
        $response["success"] = 1;

        $response["answer"] = array();

        array_push($response["answer"], $answer);

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);

    }
```

and parsing JSON

```
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_ANSWER = "answer";
private static final String TAG_BOOL1 = "bool1";
private static final String TAG_BOOL2 = "bool2";
int success;

......
...


                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest("xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "GET", params);

                    // json success tag
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        // successfully received product details
                        JSONArray answerObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ANSWER);

                        // get first product object from JSON Array
                        JSONObject answer = answerObj.getJSONObject(0);


                        String bool1s = answer.getString(TAG_BOOL1));
                        String bool2s = answer.getString(TAG_BOOL2));
                        }else{
                        .......
                        ....
```

Comment: I see and then how in my function could I check the elements of that array?

Comment: you parse json string, see above

Comment: I updates my function, I'm getting a parsing error; do you see anything wrong? I've updated my PHP also

Comment: when you response is {"success":1,"answer":[{"startingBool":"0","endingBool":"1"}]} then JSONObject answer2 = answerObj.getJSONObject(0); only one item of array and then
 String bool2s = answer2.getString(TAG_BOOL2);

Comment: when your response is {"success":1,"answer":[{"bool1":"0","bool2":"1"},{"bool1":"0","bool2":"1"}]} then you can use answer2 = answerObj.getJSONObject(1);

Comment: Ah I see, so I was looking into an element that didn't exist

Comment: what does your jasonParser class look like? Does it return a json object or an array?

Comment: My JSONParser return JSONObject

Comment: `jObj = new JSONObject(json);` as your parser return?

Comment: I have error: `JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject`

Comment: my returned object from JSON is: `[{"startingBool":"1","endingBool":"0"}]`

Comment: is it return from jsonparser ?

Comment: this [{"startingBool":"1","endingBool":"0"}] is JSONArray return from my parser is like this {"answer":[{"startingBool":"1","endingBool":"0"}]}

Comment: Log.d("From parser", json.toString()); and see your logcat

Answer (score 0):

when you have jsonarray try get value

```
JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(LOGIN_URL);
JSONObject json_obj = json.getJSONObject(0); 
String bool1s = json_obj.getString(TAG_BOOL1);
String bool2s = json_obj.getString(TAG_BOOL2);
```